# WooCommerce Plugin: Installation on WordPress site not creating required tables to function

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

After downloading a WooCommerce theme onto my WordPress website, it doesn't allow various actions.

I enabled `debug to true` in the config file and I pretty much got this monster list when I clicked "add new product".

I'm not sure what's happened where.

---

```
    WordPress database error: [Table 'victoriabakos_.wp_wc_admin_notes' doesn't exist]
SELECT note_id FROM wp_wc_admin_notes WHERE name = 'wc-admin-wc-helper-connection' ORDER BY note_id ASC

WordPress database error: [Table 'victoriabakos_.wp_wc_admin_notes' doesn't exist]
SELECT note_id FROM wp_wc_admin_notes WHERE name = 'wc-admin-wc-helper-connection' ORDER BY note_id ASC

WordPress database error: [Table 'victoriabakos_.wp_wc_admin_notes' doesn't exist]
SELECT note_id FROM wp_wc_admin_notes WHERE name = 'wc-admin-wc-helper-subscription' ORDER BY note_id ASC

WordPress database error: [Table 'victoriabakos_.wp_wc_admin_notes' doesn't exist]
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wp_wc_admin_notes`

WordPress database error: [Table 'victoriabakos_.wp_wc_admin_note_actions' doesn't exist]
DELETE FROM wp_wc_admin_note_actions WHERE note_id = 0

WordPress database error: [Table 'victoriabakos_.wp_wc_admin_note_actions' doesn't exist]
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wp_wc_admin_note_actions`

WordPress database error: [Table 'victoriabakos_.wp_wc_admin_note_actions' doesn't exist]
SELECT action_id, name, label, query, status, is_primary FROM wp_wc_admin_note_actions WHERE note_id = 0

WordPress database error: [Table 'victoriabakos_.wp_wc_admin_notes' doesn't exist]
SELECT note_id FROM wp_wc_admin_notes WHERE name = 'wc-update-db-reminder' ORDER BY note_id ASC

WordPress database error: [Table 'victoriabakos_.wp_actionscheduler_actions' doesn't exist]
SELECT a.action_id FROM wp_actionscheduler_actions a WHERE a.hook='woocommerce_update_marketplace_suggestions' AND a.status='in-progress' ORDER BY scheduled_date_gmt DESC LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'victoriabakos_.wp_actionscheduler_actions' doesn't exist]
SELECT a.action_id FROM wp_actionscheduler_actions a WHERE a.hook='woocommerce_update_marketplace_suggestions' AND a.status='pending' ORDER BY scheduled_date_gmt ASC LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'victoriabakos_.wp_actionscheduler_actions' doesn't exist]
SELECT a.action_id FROM wp_actionscheduler_actions a WHERE 1=1 AND a.hook='woocommerce_update_marketplace_suggestions' AND a.status='pending' ORDER BY a.scheduled_date_gmt ASC LIMIT 0, 1000

WordPress database error: [Table 'victoriabakos_.wp_actionscheduler_actions' doesn't exist]
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wp_actionscheduler_actions`


Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Error saving action: Error saving action: Table 'victoriabakos_.wp_actionscheduler_actions' doesn't exist in /var/www/vhosts/toasty.wine/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/action-scheduler/classes/migration/ActionScheduler_DBStoreMigrator.php:44 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/toasty.wine/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/action-scheduler/classes/data-stores/ActionScheduler_HybridStore.php(225): ActionScheduler_DBStoreMigrator->save_action(Object(ActionScheduler_Action), NULL) #1 /var/www/vhosts/toasty.wine/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/action-scheduler/classes/ActionScheduler_ActionFactory.php(177): ActionScheduler_HybridStore->save_action(Object(ActionScheduler_Action)) #2 /var/www/vhosts/toasty.wine/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/action-scheduler/classes/ActionScheduler_ActionFactory.php(84): ActionScheduler_ActionFactory->store(Object(ActionScheduler_Action)) #3 /var/www/vhosts/toasty.wine/httpdocs/wp-content/plug in /var/www/vhosts/toasty.wine/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/action-scheduler/classes/migration/ActionScheduler_DBStoreMigrator.php on line 44
There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

Learn more about debugging in WordPress.

WordPress database error: [Table 'victoriabakos_.wp_actionscheduler_actions' doesn't exist]
SELECT a.action_id FROM wp_actionscheduler_actions a WHERE a.hook='action_scheduler/migration_hook' AND a.status='in-progress' ORDER BY scheduled_date_gmt DESC LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Table 'victoriabakos_.wp_actionscheduler_actions' doesn't exist]
SELECT a.action_id FROM wp_actionscheduler_actions a WHERE a.hook='action_scheduler/migration_hook' AND a.status='pending' ORDER BY scheduled_date_gmt ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What it shows when you go to Woocommerce->Status->Tools and then click on Product Lookup Tables.

Comment: simplified the question

Answer (score 0):

from all that i've gathered, this 'missing table' error seems to arise for those who used the WooCommerce Admin plugin during the plugin's development.

the solution(s) i've come across are:

- manually adding the tables into your database
- downgrading the Woo Admin plugin, then force (re)installing each release (ideally through WP-CLI)
- downgrading the WooCommerce plugin, then force (re)installing WC v4.3, 4.4, 4.5 releases

all of those upgrades aren't required, but i also found that i had other missing tables and table mods. that sequence fixed the problem for me... because i also found myself in this problem, of being an early adapter of Woo Admin.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was to deactivate Woocommerce then activate it again to insert those missing tables.